# Netbeans 8 complaining about SF4 namespaces

Tags: netbeans, symfony4, psr-0

I have a bunch of classes in src/Controller, src/Entity, src/Form etc. For each of them Netbeans tells me that "namespace declaration name doesn't correspond to current directory structure".
My namespaces:

```
namespace App\Controller;
namespace App\Entity;
namespace App\Form;
```

Is it Symfony or Netbeans issue? Is it something to be worried about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with Symfony, and there is nothing to be worried about. The contradiction is as follow:

Symfony4 structure is based in namespaces but still is under `src/` directory the default namespace is `App` and netbeans expects your namespace to be something like `src/Controller/MyController` or any other pattern that matches with the folder structure.
Also the standard used by Symfony to autoload files is [psr-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/), to check this you may take a look at composer.json or under composer installation directory.

Try to check the netbeans configuration under *Tools->Options->Editor->Hints->PHP->PSR* and select the proper autoload configuration

You can check the diferences of [psr-0](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) and [psr-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) to understand why netbeans is throwing those warnings.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, seems that all I can do is to uncheck Namespace declaration under Hints for psr-0.